# lldb: how do i 'watch' the contents of an array

Tags: arrays, debugging, lldb

How to 'watch' the inside contents of an array using a watchpoint similar to gdb, where setting a watchpoint on an array variable hits the 'watch' on any change in the entire array. example (gdb) :

```
Hardware watchpoint 2: c

Old value = {1, 2, 0}
New value = {0, 2, 0}
```

how to achieve the same (if possible) in lldb?

Comment: AFAIK, LLDB only allows hardware watchpoints.  On x86, this limits you to a total of 4 watchpoints, each monitoring a 1, 2, 4, or 8 -byte long region of memory (with some alignment restrictions).

If you're content to watch at most 32 bytes of the array at a time (or less, depending on the alignment), you can achieve your goal by creating up to four LLDB watchpoints.


If that's not good enough, you may be able to get an equivalent effect, albeit with much slower speed, by stepping through the program on instruction at a time, looking for changes after each step.